# Tags on prototyping tools?

Tags: discussion, tags

I looked at the list of tags and stumbled upon [axure](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axure) (just 1 question tagged with this right now). If we keep this one might argue that we also need a 'Balsamiq' tag etc.

This tag might be covered by [prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping) or [tools](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) but it doesn't feel accurate.

So my question is:

**Should we delete** [axure](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axure) **and eventually create a new tag 'prototyping-tools'?**

Comment: I'm torn on this one. Note that Q was migrated to super user...I'm not sure the simple "how to use x" questions are a match here or not. There's something to be said for keeping the questions high level

Answer (score 1):

We should keep the `axure` tag and possibly add a `balsamiq` one where relevant. The more specific and more useful the tags, the better this site becomes. If I have a problem with Balsamiq, or I'm an expert on Balsamiq, it's extremely helpful if there's a way to filter all questions by those specifically about Balsamiq.

However let's limit those tags to tools that are staples. I think Axure and Balsamiq meet those requirements, but not many others. Beyond those two it's probably best to review on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Indeed those two tools are widely used and very good examples for specific use cases. But there are so many more tools that it doesn't feel right just to highlight the two -- see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/375/what-are-some-great-web-based-prototyping-tools

Comment: The others aren't remotely as popular or as well-known. Unless they are (which we can determine on a case-by-case basis, like I said in my answer), we should just do these two for now.

Answer (score 1):

As Rahul says, more specific tags are better than fewer generic ones. We just have to ensure that the tagging practice for these questions is done logically.

For prototyping, unless it's a specific Axure (or Balsamiq) question then these questions should just be tagged:

[prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping)

but if it's a specific prototyping question about Axure then it should be tagged:

[prototyping](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prototyping) [axure](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axure)

This is a similar approach to how [gaming.stackexchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) handle tags:

If you have a question regarding how to solve a puzzle in **Skyrim** for example then the question is tagged [skyrim](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) but if you have a Skyrim question that would only be relevant to PC users (such as how to work with modifications) then they would be tagged [skyrim](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) [pc](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc)

Comment: Agreed on the need for the generic tag too.